# How do you plot a segment on a figure where the axis is categorial?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I managed to create a scatterplot using seaborn and matplotlib where I have the continuous variable `LifeExp` on the y-axis and the categorical variable `continent` on the x-axis, and I plotted the life expectancy for the 3 different continents (with some jitter). **I would like now to add a segment for the mean of each continent.**

### Here is the code and the plot generated:

```
from gapminder import gapminder
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gapminder_2007 = gapminder.loc[gapminder['year'] == 2007]
gapminder_3_continents = gapminder_2007.loc[(gapminder_2007['continent'] == "Europe") | (gapminder_2007['continent'] == "Americas") | (gapminder_2007['continent'] == "Africa")]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(7, 5))
sns.set(style='ticks', context='talk')
sns.stripplot('continent', 'lifeExp', data=gapminder_3_continents, jitter=0.2)
sns.despine()
plt.axhline(y=gapminder_3_continents["lifeExp"].mean(), color='green', ls='-')
```

[image]

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "segment"?

Comment: A line segment. Something similar to what you can do with "plt.hlines()" if you have a continuous x-axis